# definition of ruby inbuilt methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I go throw this [guide-ruby-collections-iv-tips-tricks](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-ruby-collections-iv-tips-tricks/) article

```
Array.new(3, rand(100))
```

That wasn’t exactly random. It looks like `rand(100)` is only being evaluated once. Fortunately, `Array#new` can take a block, and it will run the block for each element, assigning the element the result.

```
Array.new(3) { rand(100) }
=> [10,53,27]
```

**That' ok**

But where I could see the actual implementation of `#new` method of `Array class`,  I checked with [Array's New Method](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-c-new)  But Still not getting the point.

As I'm using `Rubymine` I checked with there also ,**this is I found there**

```
def self.new(*several_variants)
    #This is a stub, used for indexing
end
```

**1:** What is meaning of `*several_variants` here.

**2:** Where if the actual definition of this method.

Suppose I've a `class Test; end`

How might I could write `#new` method which can accept `array, optional-hash and block` ?

Comment: i'm looking for the definition for ruby method  so that i could write my own method, like #link_to and as you told the implementation in 'C' so how might i can write my own 'my_each' method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1: what is meaning of *several_variants here.

It's a 'splat.':

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> def foo(*bar)
irb(main):002:1> puts bar
irb(main):003:1> puts bar.class
irb(main):004:1> end
=> :foo
irb(main):005:0> foo([1, 2, 3])
1
2
3
Array
=> nil
irb(main):006:0> foo("hello")
hello
Array
=> nil
irb(main):007:0> foo("Hello", "world")
Hello
world
Array
=> nil
irb(main):008:0> foo(a: "hash")
{:a=>"hash"}
Array
=> nil
```

2: where if the actual definition of this method.

It's in C: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/array.c#L5746 and https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/array.c#L722-L777

```
rb_ary_initialize(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE ary)
```

Of course, that's not as helpful, since:

> how might i write #new method which can accept array, optional hash and block ?

Usually, in Ruby, you don't write a `new`, you write an `initialize`. `new` calls `initialize`. Doing this is as easy as:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(*args, &blk)
    # stuff goes here
  end
end
```

`args` will have all the arguments, and `&blk` will have a block, if you were passed one.