# How to understand the core concept of #map method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I read this article [about enumerable-enumerator](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-ruby-collections-iii-enumerable-enumerator/).  `map` is method of the `Enumerable`:

```
module Enumerable
    def map(*several_variants) ## `*several_variants`  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28527931/definition-of-ruby-inbuilt-methods][2]
        #This is a stub, used for indexing
    end
end

class Enumerator  # Enumerator class has included Enumerable module Ok fine !!!
    include Enumerable # many  thing are there ...    
end
```

And in the `Array` class:

```
 class Array # Array class has included Enumerable module it means all the instances methods of  Enumerable module will expose as the instance methods in  Array class !!! Okk
     include Enumerable  # many  thing are there ...
 end
```

Now when I call the `map` method on an array, I get an `Enumerator`:

```
[1,2,3,4].map   => #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4]:map>
```

**1:** What is  `Enumerator` in the `#<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4]:map>` line of output above?

```
 module Test

  def initialize(str)
    @str = str
  end

  def methods_1(str)
    p "Hello!!#{str}"
  end
 end

 class MyTest
  include Test
  include Enumerable
 end

 my_test = MyTest.new('Ruby')
 p  "Which class ? : #{my_test}"
 my_test.methods_1('Rails')
 p my_test.map
```

**Output**

```
"Which class ? : #<MyTest:0x000000019e6e38>"
"Hello!!Rails"
#<Enumerator: #<MyTest:0x000000019e6e38 @str="Ruby">:map>
```

**2:** This should be **object of MyTest class** only if i'm not wrong.

**3:** In this line `#<Enumerator: #<MyTest:0x000000019e6e38 @str="Ruby">:map>`, what does `Enumerator` do here?

**Thanks for all** to making this concept clear,  in short span of time.
I would like to share some useful link to grasp the concept at great level.

[Map, Select, and Other Enumerable Methods](http://www.eriktrautman.com/posts/ruby-explained-map-select-and-other-enumerable-methods)

[What does the “map” method do in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084507/what-does-the-map-method-do-in-ruby)

[Enumerable and Enumerator](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-ruby-collections-iii-enumerable-enumerator/)

[Ruby tricks to make your code more fun and less readable](https://coderwall.com/p/qfh2ua/ruby-tricks-to-make-your-code-more-fun-and-less-readable)

Comment: Your second "question" is not a question.  What does "This should be object of MyTest class only if i'm not wrong" mean?

Comment: what I’m trying to say is , I’m calling `map` method of `Enumerable module` on  `my_test` object which is the object of `MyTest` `class` so it should be return `MyTest` class only

Comment: That's not true at all.  Why would `map` return an instance of `MyTest`?  What does this have to do with the `Enumerable` module?  `methods_1` is from the `Test` module, do you expect `my_test.methods_1('Rails')` to return an instance of `MyTest` as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your question is specific to `Enumerable#map`. If you browse the [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when) module, you'll find many methods (including `map`) that return one thing if a block is given and an enumerator if no block is given. Suppose you wrote,

```
[1,2,3].map.with_index { |x,idx| x+idx } #=> [1,3,5]
```

`map` is not given a block, so it returns an enumerator:

```
enum1 = [1,2,3].map
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:map>
```

The method [Enumerator#with_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) is then sent to `enum1`:

```
enum2 = enum1.with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:map>:with_index>
```

As you see, `enum2` is also an enumerator, a sort of "compound enumerator".

`enum2` does have a block, so it's elements are passed into the block by the method [Enumerator#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-each), which calls [Array#each](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each).

We can view the contents of any enumerator by converting it to an array:

```
enum2.to_a
  #=> [[1, 0], [2, 1], [3, 2]]
```

This shows us the elements that `each` will pass into the block, the first being the array `[1, 0]`, causing the block variable `x` to be assigned the value `1` and the block variable `idx` to be assigned `0`.

The final step in the calculation is performed by `Array#each`:

```
enum2.each { |x,idx| x+idx } #=> [1,3,5]
```

The docs for `Enumerator#with_index` (as well as for `map` and most other `Enumerable` methods) says that it is returns an object (generally not an enumerator) when it is given a block, and returns an enumerator when it is not given a block. As I've just shown, however, it's really producing an enumerator in any case; when it is followed by a block, it call's upon the receiver's class' `each` method to do its thing.

Yes, you can `include Enumerable` in your owns classes, but to use that module's methods you must also define the method `each` for your class.

It's enumerators that allow us to chain methods, and to do that efficiently, without creating temporary arrays and other such objects between the links.

I once gave the following fanciful account of how the `Enumerable` module came into existence:

One day, long ago, a very wise Rubyest from the land of the Rising Sun noticed that many methods he used for arrays were very similar to those he used for hashes, ranges and other collections. He saw that he could write them so that the only difference was how the method "each" was implemented, so he put them all in a module he called "可算の" ("Enumerable"), and then in all the classes for different types of collections he added "include Enumerable" and a method "each". After doing this, he thought, "生活は快適です" ("life is good").

Comment: now i get it . one more thing why we need to create each method? as you wrote in your answer _so that the only difference was how the method "each" was implemented_

Comment: My apologies for the late reply. Enumerable methods must know how to pass objects from the receiver into the block, which varies by class. If `each` were not defined by class you could not change it, and you could not `include Enumerable` in your own classes. Here's an analogy: [Yakima](http://www.yakima.com/) makes roof racks for hundreds of different makes and models of cars.  The way they do it is to sell "universal racks" that attach to your car with a small piece of hardware designed specifically for your car. That's their `each` method. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea of `map` method is that, for every iteration of an element, `map` inserts the value of the last expression executed in the block into a new array. After the last element is executed, `map` returns to you the `new array` of values.

In your example:

1. `Enumerator` is just a class in Ruby. You've instantiated it when you didn't add a block on `[1,2,3,4].map`. Take note that it's different from `Enumerable`
2. Yes, it is your **MyTest** class. If you like to test it, do `my_test.class`
3. You just instantiated an `Enumerator` object by doing `my_test.map` and ruby saw that you've included the `Enumerable` module in your class.

Comment: Ok @Finks i checked with the Enumerator and Enumerable again but still one doubt  `[1,2,3,4].map
 => #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4]:map> `   why `Enumerator` came here ..       Can you give me any Example..

Comment: Because there are multiple ways to instantiate an `Enumerator`, 1 is adding `map` method like what you did. You can also do `[1,2,3,4].each` or just using any of the `Enumerable` methods.

Answer (score 0):

The most common usage of `map` is with a block, like so:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].map { |n| n*n }
# => [1, 4, 9, 16]
```

However, if you call `map` without passing a block, it still returns something.  In this case it returns an `Enumerator` which knows about the original array and that it's a "map" type of array.  It can be used to chain other `Enumerator` methods, for instance:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].map.with_index { |n, idx| "entry #{idx} squared: #{n*n}" }
# => ["entry 0 squared: 1", "entry 1 squared: 4", "entry 2 squared: 9", "entry 3 squared: 16"]
```

You can read more documentation on [the `Enumerator` class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html) but in practice, you probably want to understand how to use `map` with blocks more.

Comment: could you please explain a bit about the line that you written _In this case it returns an Enumerator which knows about the original array and that it's a "map" type of array._